# Nuclear vs Integral operators on Hilbert spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, operator-theory, traces

Consider the Hilbert space $L_2=L_2[0,1]$. Is it true that for each nuclear (trace-class) operator on $L_2$ there exists a function $K\in L_1(L_2)$ such that

$$Tf = \int\limits_0^1 K(s) f(s) \,\mu(\mbox{d}s)?$$

The above is an integral in the sense of Bochner.

It seems to be a part of the folkolre but I was unable to trace a reference. Is it true for nuclear operator on $L_p$ where $p\in (1,\infty)$?

Comment: I assume $X$ is supposed to be $[0,1]$ and $\mu$ Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Also, I don't see why the operator defined by your formula is bounded (you need something stronger than $K\in L^1(L^2)$ I think)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each trace class operator on $L_2(0,1)$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, but not conversely.

Each $L_2(0,1)$-function is in $L_1(0,1)$, but not conversely.

Each Hilbert-Schmidt operator on $L_2$ is uniquely determined by an $L_2(L_2)$-function - indeed, it is an integral operator with $L_2(L_2)$ kernel.

So, the answer to your first question is yes, but I guess the answer to the second one is no.

The relation between tensor products and $L_p$-spaces is horrible, cf. the final page of this note (http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.2038), so I doubt that your last question cannot have an affirmative answer.